# Custom page give 404 in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new in Bigcommerce. I have created Stencil-cli on my local add create a custom page help of below URL

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwrVN5QrEZY&t=437s
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/storefront-customization/custom-templates

After mapping in config.stencil.json

```
"customLayouts": {
        "brand": {},
        "category": {},
        "page": {},
        "product": { "product-size-chart.html": "/larry-bowie-tee/" }
    }
```

stencil start command an it's run successfully.

```
-------------------------------------------------

[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:3001
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.91:3000
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3002
 UI External: http://localhost:3002
 -------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to D:\xampp\htdocs\bigcommerce\demo\assets\dist\report.html
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

But When I hit new URL it's given 404 page not found.

```
http://localhost:3000/larry-bowie-tee/
```

I already make bundle from **stencil bundle** and run again **stencil start**

Please help how to create custom page and run locally from **stencil**

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a page with that URL in your store? Here is a guide on how to do this: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Web-Pages